# How to split an array with recursion

Tags: python, matlab

Hi I'll explain what I need. I want to obtain using recursion a way to split an array into subarrays dividing at the half of each subarray.

I mean for example if I have an array a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

I want to obtain from that this array of arrays: h = [[1,2], [3,4], [1], [2], [3], [4]]

I'm trying multiple ways and think recursion is the best way to do it but I can't reach how to do it.

Comment: What should the result be for an odd-lengthed array?

Comment: for an odd-lengthed array could be for example if the array is [1,2,3] can be [[1], [2,3], [2],[3]]

Comment: But I think if work only for even numbers should be good cause I have to take exactly two half of all the subarrays so it's supposed to be all array of even length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Matlab solution (note put both functions in a single file called split_array.m):

```
function O = split_array(I)
% Wrapper function to sort the output of the recursive output
    O = split_array_R(I);
    [~,ind] = sort(cellfun(@numel, O), 'descend');
    O = O(ind);
end

function O = split_array_R(I, I1, I2)

    if ~iscell(I)
        n = ceil(numel(I)/2);
        I1 = I(1:n);
        I2 = I(n+1:end);
        I = {I};
    end;

    if numel(I1) > 1
        O1 = split_array_R(I1);
    else
        O1 = {I1};
    end

    if numel(I2) > 1
        O2 = split_array_R(I2);
    else
        O2 = {I2};
    end

    O = {I{:}, O1{:}, O2{:}};
end
```

Comment: well it gives me cell arrays into O as output, I have to convert it to integers

Comment: How to use each subarray as a simple array of integers so not using cells?

Comment: Well... if it was a simple array how would you know where each set starts and finishes? Your example output was a tuple of tuples which I think translates to a matlab cell array of regular arrays like this solution provides. You can get any element as a normal array just by using the `{}` for indexing: e.g. `O{3}`

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
>>> def split_array(array):
        if len(array) <= 1:
            return array
        else:
            return [array[:len(array)//2], array[len(array)//2:]]


>>> def halves(array):
        if len(array) <= 1:
            return [array]
        else:
            parts = split_array(array)
            return [array] + halves(parts[0]) + halves(parts[1])


>>> halves([1, 2, 3, 4])
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2], [1], [2], [3, 4], [3], [4]]
>>> halves([1, 2, 3, 4])[1:]
[[1, 2], [1], [2], [3, 4], [3], [4]]
```

This doesn't produce the subarrays in order. I would use an iterative approach for that.

Comment: The order is not important, I have to use the values in a binary tree so it's useful the algorithm you wrote like it is

Comment: it works also for great arrays? I mean array of more than 100 element?

Comment: Yes, it works up to at least 1000 elements (although it's quite slow).

Comment: @sweeneyrod I'm sure you could do exactly what I did to change the order in matlab in Python? Do you know how to get a vector of where the indices moved in Python like the second output of sort in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, using cells and only for even-lengthed array

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b= a(1:numel(a)/2);
c= a(numel(a)/2+1:end); 
d= num2cell(a);
%
O={b,c,d{:}};
```

Read values:

```
O{i} with i={1,...,6}
```

**EDIT**
For odd- and even-lengthed array (but for odd-lengthed array you need to adjust the value of `r` in function of the split you want)

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
r = floor(numel(a)/2);
b= a(1:r);
c= a(r+1:end); 
d= num2cell(a);
%
O={b,c,d{:}};
```

Comment: @Dan I agree and it is why I wrote _even_. In fact it is working for `numel(a)=2*p` where `p` is an integer (`numel(a)`is even)..

Comment: no it doesn't work for all even numbers. If `numel(a) == 8` for example, you'll leave off all the splits of `numel` 2 etc...